# javascript infinite loop error multidimensional array sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, infinite-loop

Iam trying to sort a multidimension array and put the highest numbers of each sub-array in an array with a double loop but iam getting an infinite loop error for some reason:

The array to be sorted:

```
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

The code:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var largestNumber = 0;
        for (var j = 0; i < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (largestNumber < arr[i][j]) {
                largestNumber = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        temp[i] = largestNumber;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: `i < arr[i].length`?

Comment: `i < arr[i].length` shoud be `j < arr[i].length`

Answer (score 1):

You need two changes, one for the right type of the variable to assign the result, and the check in the for loop with the right variable.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var temp = []; // necessary
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var largestNumber = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            //          ^^ j instead of i 
            if (largestNumber < arr[i][j]) {
                largestNumber = arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        temp[i] = largestNumber;
    }
    return temp;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```